# Using Vector images as an image source. WPF , C#

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, vector, imagesource

How can one use a vector image as a source such as:

```
<Image Width="70" Height="70" Source="MyVectorImage"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DrawingImage` as the Image's Source. DrawingImage uses a Geometry (i.e. vector graphics) instead of a bitmap.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <DrawingImage>
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Thickness="2" Brush="Black"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="100,100,100,100"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

You can of course also bind the Source property to a view model property of type ImageSource, which contains a DrawingImage that you would create from your original vector data.

Comment: how  can i bind the Source property to a view model property of type ImageSource ? and how do i get the Geometry of my .ai file ?

Comment: Please search the web for MVVM and WPF data binding. When you create a view model class, add a property of type ImageSource. In your view model class, convert your vector data to an appropriate Greometry and assign it to the Geometry property of a DrawingImage. Then return the DrawingImage from the property getter.

Comment: Of course it might be simpler to use a Path element and bind its Data property to a Geometry.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the `ImageSource` from a geometry path image into your cs file, you can put the `drawingImage` into a resource file: `Icons.xaml`:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="hazelnut">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <GeometryGroup>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 16.6309,18.6563C 17.1309,8.15625 29.8809,14.1563 29.8809,14.1563C 30.8809,11.1563 34.1308,11.4063 34.1308,11.4063C 33.5,12 34.6309,13.1563 34.6309,13.1563C 32.1309,13.1562 31.1309,14.9062 31.1309,14.9062C 41.1309,23.9062 32.6309,27.9063 32.6309,27.9062C 24.6309,24.9063 21.1309,22.1562 16.6309,18.6563 Z M 16.6309,19.9063C 21.6309,24.1563 25.1309,26.1562 31.6309,28.6562C 31.6309,28.6562 26.3809,39.1562 18.3809,36.1563C 18.3809,36.1563 18,38 16.3809,36.9063C 15,36 16.3809,34.9063 16.3809,34.9063C 16.3809,34.9063 10.1309,30.9062 16.6309,19.9063 Z ">
                            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform
                                        CenterX="23"
                                        CenterY="20"
                                        ScaleX="0.45"
                                        ScaleY="0.45" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </PathGeometry.Transform>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

And add in you `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icons.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And use it in your cs file like:

```
    ImageSource image = ResourcePathToImageSource("hazelnut");


    private ImageSource ResourcePathToImageSource(string resourcesName)
    {
        return (DrawingImage)Application.Current.TryFindResource(resourcesName);
    }
```